# A Unicode string written in escaped ASCII

Tags: python, unicode, ascii

I use a  PHP/webservice with Python but it returns me troubles :
Where I want to have `u'Syst\xe8me'`, I have `u'Syst\xc3\xa8me'`.

And I don't how to go from B to A.

PS: I've already try to set `encoding='ascii'` in my `xmlrpclib.Server`.

Comment: Maybe you want to set encoding='utf-8', since Python is already (correctly?) generating UTF-8 data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Latin-1 (aka ISO 8859-1) encoding can be used to convert characters less than 256 to bytes.

```
>>> u'Syst\xc3\xa8me'.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
u'Syst\xe8me'
```